# Adding a custom button to Woocommerce product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In the Woocommerce product page I have added an extra button ,that redirects to another page, under the 'Add to Cart' button using the following code:

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button','content_after_addtocart_button' );

function content_after_addtocart_button() {
echo '<br><div class="content-section">
<br><br> Cannot find the specs you need? Order your customized product! <br> 
<br>
<button type="submit" formaction="https://xxxx.com/custom- 
product/">Demand a custom product</button><br>
</div>';
}
```

There is no problem clicking the button then being redirected to that page but opening the product page again gives the following error alert:
    Please choose product options..
or this error alert:
    Sorry, this product cannot be purchased.
This error never shows up before clicking the custom button. How can I fix that? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue with a workaround. I enclosed the button in a link and referred it to the URL of the other page, as follows:

```
<a href="https://xxxx.com/custom-product/"><button type="button" style="border:2;">Order a custom product</button></a>
```

I assigned the button's type attribute to "button" and it's now working fine but I'm not sure if keeping it "submit" will render any errors. Rather change it to "button".